# What is Difference between <rewrite> and <drewrite> tag

Tags: magento-1.9

In Config.xml of an Extension i have seen `<drewrite>` tag used to rewrite the block. What is the difference between `<rewrite>` and `<drewrite>` tag?

Comment: I doubt this is typo or was used in old version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I go through the Whole code, the `<drewrite>` is a custom node created to used by observer.

Answer (score 4):

I've never seen this in any core file or custom extension. I'm willing to bet it's a typo.

Can you verify that the rewrite is not actually being applied?

Comment: i have edited the question and added the related code

Comment: Search your code base for the word `drewrite` all lower case. There is nothing vanilla as far as I can see, but it's possible some custom module is accessing that part of the config for strange and unusual reasons.

Comment: I did a grep of a Stock magento Install for drewrite  with the following command  grep -R "drewrite" app/code/core   It returned no results

Answer (score 2):

`drewrite` does nothing. My bet is, that "d" stands for "disabled" or maybe "deprecated" and the developer found this more appropiate than using XML comments or just removing the code that's not used anymore.

It goes without saying that this is not good practice.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is `<rewrite>` exists in magento configuration, `<drewrite>` does not. Probably just a typo...

Answer (score 0):

"drewrite" is not Magento specific. Some extensions like "Aw/Blog" use the node "drewrite" on configuration dependence. That means, if some extension config value is present, the extension uses the event observer to rename the "drewrite" node to "rewrite", so that the class rewrite can happen during runtime.

"drewrite" could stand for dynamic rewrite.